# Fixed-sized memory pool in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm learning C and I am currently implementing a memory pool.

I'm writing it in steps, first I implemented a fixed-sized memory pool then I will try to implement a memory pool with a known size of elements but an unknown number of elements and ultimately try to write a generic one that is just a block of memory that can allocate any size.

The pool is actually a block of memory that is initialized with values that are pointers to the next memory like so:

```
 ______________
|0x8 |0x10|NULL|
|____|____|____|
 ^    ^    ^
 0x0  0x8  0x10
```

I want to know if I'm heading in the right direction.
There is the code

allocator.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct FixedPoolAllocator FixedPoolAllocator;

FixedPoolAllocator* FixedPoolAllocator_new(size_t nmemb, size_t size);

void* FixedPoolAllocator_alloc(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator);

void FixedPoolAllocator_free(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator, void *ptr);

void FixedPoolAllocator_destroy(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator);
```

allocator.c:

```
#include "allocator.h"

#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

typedef struct FixedPoolAllocator {

    // The currently free space in which a value can be stored
    size_t *currentFree;
    size_t numOfMembers;
    size_t memberSize;
    // The actual memory block, It is of type char* so that pointer arithmetic will be easier
    char *mem;

} FixedPoolAllocator;

FixedPoolAllocator* FixedPoolAllocator_new(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    if (0 == size || 0 == nmemb) return NULL;

    FixedPoolAllocator *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    if (NULL == ret) return NULL;

    // Make sure that the size of each member is atleast size_t so that the members can store a memory address
    size_t member_size = MAX(sizeof(size_t), size);

    ret->mem = malloc(nmemb * member_size);
    if (NULL == ret->mem) return NULL;
    // The initial free member
    ret->currentFree = (size_t*)ret->mem;

    ret->numOfMembers = nmemb;
    ret->memberSize = size;

    size_t *temp = ret->currentFree;

    // Assign each member with the address of the next member
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < nmemb - 1; i++) {
        *temp = (size_t) (ret->mem + (i+1) * member_size);
        temp = (size_t*) ((char*)temp + member_size);
    }

    // The last member points to NULL
    *temp = (size_t)NULL;

    return ret;
}

void* FixedPoolAllocator_alloc(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator)
{
    if (NULL == allocator || NULL == allocator->currentFree) return NULL;

    // Return the currently free member and update currentFree to the next member in the list
    void *ret = allocator->currentFree;
    allocator->currentFree = (size_t*)*allocator->currentFree;

    return ret;
}

void FixedPoolAllocator_free(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator, void *ptr)
{
    size_t ptr_as_value = (size_t)ptr;

    // Assign the pointed value with the current free member
    *(size_t*)ptr = (size_t)allocator->currentFree;
    // Update the currenty free member to be the one that was just freed
    allocator->currentFree = ptr;
}

void FixedPoolAllocator_destroy(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator)
{
    free(allocator->mem);

    free(allocator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the post, and I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Curious, why prohibit `size == 0` with `if (0 == size || 0 == nmemb) return NULL;` versus `if (0 == nmemb) return NULL;`.  I see nothing in code that that prevents use of `size == 0`.

Comment: Because calling malloc(member_size*nmemb) when size == 0 would allocate memory that isn't really needed

Answer (score 4):

Only a small review

**Alignment not guaranteed**

`temp = (size_t*) ((char*)temp + member_size);` attempts to convert a `char*` to `size_t *`, yet `(char*)temp + member_size` is not known to be properly aligned for a `size_t*`.  Insufficient alignment is *undefined behavior*.

**Detect overflow**

As the true product of `nmemb * member_size` may exceed `SIZE_MAX`:

```
if (SIZE_MAX/nmemb > member_size) {
  Handle_Overflow();  // clean-up, return NULL;
}
... =  malloc(nmemb * member_size);
```

**Strange uses of `size_t` as pointer**

`// The last member points to NULL` `*temp = (size_t)NULL;` implies something wrong.  If codes needs a pointer, use a pointer, not `size_t`.  If code needs a size, doesn't use a pointer.  Note that `size_t` and pointers do not necessarily covert well back and forth.  They might not be the same memory width either.

This use of `size_t` as a place to encode a pointer is simply broken.  Code needs a new approach.

Comment: I actually just read about the notion of 'memory alignment' and I will definitely be fixing that. When I wrote (size_t)NULL it was so that the compiler won't give me a warning about assining (void*) to size_t.

Comment: Also, is there some way to know what is the memory alignement of the CPU in C?

Comment: @JimMorrison "to know what is the memory alignement": Research `max_align_t` for C99 or later, else align to a union of wide types  `double`, `long`, `void*` and `int (*)()`  (a function pointer).  Detail: it is not the alignment requirement of the CPU needed, but the alignment requirement the compiler imposes (which may be more stringent than the CPU).

Answer (score 3):

If you want enough size to fit a `void*` then actually use `sizeof(void*)`. If you really want to use an integer type instead of a pointer type then use `intptr_t` instead of `size_t`.

```
size_t member_size = MAX(sizeof(void*), size);
```

You leak if you fail to allocate the actual pool:

```
if (NULL == ret->mem) {
    free(ret);
    return NULL;
}
```

Initializing the pool can be done simpler:

```
// Assign each member with the address of the next member
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < nmemb - 1; i++) {
    *temp = (void*) ((char*)temp + member_size);
    temp = (void*) ((char*)temp + member_size);
}
```

You can also avoid that entire initialization loop by using an extra member that marks the high water mark (the furthest element that was ever allocated) and is used when `allocator->currentFree == NULL`:

```
void* FixedPoolAllocator_alloc(FixedPoolAllocator *allocator)
{
    if (NULL == allocator) return NULL;

    if (NULL == allocator->currentFree)
    {
        // nothing in freelist, increment highWater
        if (allocator->highWater == ret->numOfMembers) return NULL;

        void *ret = (void*) (allocator->mem + allocator->highWater);
        allocator->highWater += allocator->memberSize;
        return ret;
    }

    // Return the currently free member and update currentFree to the next member in the list
    void *ret = allocator->currentFree;
    allocator->currentFree = (void*)*allocator->currentFree;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why the unnecessary cast in `void *ret = (void*) ((char*)temp + allocator->highWater);`?  2) `void *ret = ...; ...  ret->memberSize;` is certainly wrong.